# Get a # value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, html

I have some links and when you click on them it navigates to: `foo.com/about.php#about2` and`foo.com/about.php#about1`

How can I get the `#about1` or `about2` in Javascript, so if it is `#about1` display the content relative to that div, and if it is `#about2` display that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why do you want to use that? Thats pretty much only used in client side stuff.

Comment: sorry, this is not the duplication

Comment: funny how the question just got changed from php to JS

Comment: @JanDragsbaek It is isn't it :). I got two different questions mixed up :P

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you trying to figure out what the hash part of the URL is, or are you trying to get it to automatically scroll to the DIV?

Comment: Folks, Revision 1 of this question _clearly_ says Javascript. So if it _was_ a duplicate, it became a non-duplicate within the edit grace period, and is (not) currently a duplicate.

Comment: @TimPost No, it didn't. Revision 1 is already edited. I am very sure that I got here through the PHP tag and that tag isn't present in the history, so it is definitely edited.

Comment: @NikiC I edited my comment to that affect. Anyway, the OP got the answer, more breadcrumbs exist for searching and the balance of the universe has been restored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JavaScript, is called `window.location.hash`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
window.location.hash
```